UK show about a guy who has to perform crazy challenges or he gets tortured
In the early 2000s on comedy central, Sunday night had 2 TV shows back to back.  First was Dave Attell's Insomniac. The second was some UK show about a guy who had to complete crazy challenges (like hit on another dude in a restroom), failing to complete the challenges wound up with him getting humiliated in some fashion.  The show was a blast to watch, but I have no clue what it was.. any ideas?

Sounds like Travel Sick that aired on Comedy Central in 2001-2002:

It placed UK writer Grub Smith in a different region of the world in each episode. In each destination, he was asked to complete five undesirable challenges posed by the show's producers. If he failed a challenge, he was forced to perform something unpleasant called a "forfeit". The more he failed, the worse the "forfeit" at the end of the show became.

Here's a clip from an episode in Germany:




Thats it!!!!! BEST show ever, you're awesome
